# Erro na utilizacao do Mockito. Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: java, mockito

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação mas por algum motivo o teste não está passando. Não faço a mínima ideia do motivo. Segue o erro apresentado:

> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Segue o código:

```
public class LocacaoService {

    private LocacaoDao dao;
    private EmailService emailService;


    public void notificarLocacaoEmAtraso(){
        List<Locacao> locacaoesEmAtrado = dao.obterAtrasados();
        for(Locacao locacao : locacaoesEmAtrado){
            emailService.enviarEmailCobranca(locacao.getUsuario());
        }
    }


    public void setDao(LocacaoDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void setEmailService(EmailService emailService){
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

}    


public interface LocacaoDao {

    void salvar(Locacao locacao);

    List<Locacao> obterAtrasados();
}

public interface EmailService {

    void enviarEmailCobranca(Usuario usuario);
}
```

O teste que eu fiz que está apresentando erro:

```
public class LocacaoServiceTest {

    private Usuario pedro;
    private List<Filme> filmes;
    private LocacaoService service;
    private Locacao locacao;
    private LocacaoDao dao;
    private EmailService email;

    @BeforeEach
    public void criaUsuarioLocacaoELocacaoService() {
        pedro = new Usuario("Pedro");
        filmes = new ArrayList<>();
        service = new LocacaoService();
        locacao = new Locacao();

        dao = Mockito.mock(LocacaoDao.class);
        service.setDao(dao);

        email = Mockito.mock(EmailService.class);
        service.setEmailService(email);
    }

     @Test
     public void deveEnviarEmailDeCobrança() {
        Locacao locacao = new Locacao();
        locacao.setUsuario(pedro);
        locacao.setDataRetorno(DataUtils.obterDataComDiferencaDias(-2));


        List<Locacao> pendentes = new ArrayList<>();
        pendentes.add(locacao);

        service.notificarLocacaoEmAtraso();

        Mockito.when(dao.obterAtrasados()).thenReturn(pendentes);

        Mockito.verify(email).enviarEmailCobranca(pedro);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que chamar o `when` **antes** de chamar o método sendo testado:

```
Mockito.when(dao.obterAtrasados()).thenReturn(pendentes);
service.notificarLocacaoEmAtraso();

Mockito.verify(email).enviarEmailCobranca(pedro);
```

O `when` define o que o método `obterAtrasados` deve retornar. Mas como você já estava fazendo a chamada de `notificarLocacaoEmAtraso` antes, e esta chama `obterAtrasados` (ou seja, primeiro executava o método, depois definia o que ele deveria retornar), ele acabava não retornando o valor `pendentes` que você definiu. Com isso, a lista retornada era vazia e ele não entrava no *loop*, e por isso nenhuma chamada de `enviarEmailCobranca` era feita (daí o erro de "*zero interactions with this mock*").

Chamando `when` antes, você tem o comportamento esperado. Já a chamada de `verify` continua sendo depois, pois aí ela serve para verificar se algo foi ou não executado.

---

De maneira geral, você chama `when` para definir o que *mocks* específicos irão retornar, e deve fazer isso antes do método sendo testado. E `verify` é usado depois do método sendo testado, para ver se tudo que você quer verificar de fato aconteceu.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Primeiro pela resposta nota 10 e segundo pela aula. Jamais imaginei que era esse o motivo. Obrigado!